# Explain the output of : echo (2) . (3 * (print 3));

Tags: php

I know the above code outputs 323

But need an explanation on how is it outputting 323

Anybody can pls explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

echo (2).(3*print(3));

Step1:(Starting execution)

```
echo (2).(3*print(3)); //Output = ''
```

Step 2:(Print action will take place)

```
 echo (2).(3*1); // Will print 3 and returns 1 as per print function. Output = 3
```

Step 3:(Multiplication operation)

```
 echo (2).(3);  // Multiplication operation willtake place. Output = 3
```

Step 4:(Prints the data)

```
 echo (2).(3);  //The . Operator will used to concate the strings in php, thus Output = 323
```

Print has more priority then echo thus it prints 3 first later 2 and 3

Comment: the 2 belongs to echo (2) the last 3 is 3 times the result of print(3). print returns 1 so 3 times 1 is 3. try this: var_dump(print("hi\n")) you will see that print returns 1.

Comment: Print returns 1 thus (3*1) is 3, but the print(3) need to print 3, so it prints the 3 first and after 2 then the final (3*1) will be printed as 323

Answer (score 6):

Both echo and print are intended to behave more like language constructs and not functions. As such they have a flow of control. What happens here in your code is that you are calling print from inside of a language construct (*echo*). Meaning that print will send its output first before echo has completed its task (remember you called print from inside of echo).

To show you what's happening a bit more clearly, it actually has nothing to do with operator precedence at all.

```
echo ('a') . ('b' * (print 'c')); // ca0

// This is the same thing as...

echo 'a' . 'b' * print 'c';       // ca0
```

Notice the operators have no effect on the order of the characters in the resulting output here.

print always returns 1 so what happens here is that you performed an arithmetic operation on `'b' * 1`, which is the stirng **b** multiplied by the return value of **print**. Thus why you see the output as c (print sent output before echo has even finished doing it's job), first, and then everything that echo was supposed to print.

Let me elaborate even further with the following example...

```
echo print 'a' . 'b' . 'c'; // abc1
```

Notice the 1 at the end of that output. This is because all echo did was output the return value of **print** and not the string. Instead, print is the one that provided the `abc` as output (and remember print is able to send output before echo can since echo has to wait to process everything inside of the construct before it can finish).

This makes it even more clear...

```
echo (print 'a') . 'b' . 'c'; // a1bc
```

Now the 1 comes right after a.

If you want echo to send the output for each expression individually, you can supply one argument for every expression you want processed and sent to output... So for example:

```
echo print 'a', 'b', 'c'; // a1bc
echo 2, 3 * print 3; // 233
```

I hope that clarifies it a bit more for you.

Comment: Just in case, I said print() had precedence over the previous operators precisely because is NOT an operator. That's what I meant, although it was far from clear in my answer. Very good your explanation, though.

Comment: Sure, I understood what you meant. However, *precedence* is normally associated with operators. Since print is more of a function/language-construct what we are looking at here is the effect of a call-stack. Take for example doing something like foo(bar(baz())) ... what happens here is that the function baz() must finish executing before we can return a value to function bar(), before we can return a value to function foo(). This is pretty much the same thing that happens here (it's a stack that affects our flow-of-control).

Answer (score 2):

The reason is `(print 3)` has priority over the previous operators. If you write `echo (8) . (7 * (print 3)); you will get 387, for example.