# Explain the output of : echo 'to'.print('2')+2;

Tags: php

I run this and it will produce 4to1

But need an explanation on how is it outputting 4to1

Anybody can pls explain?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737265/explain-the-output-of-echo-2-3-print-3

Comment: JiteshNK I copied pattern from same link  In my question i unable to find the answer how (+) operator work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`print('2')+2` this part of code will print the number `4` to start of the line. `Print` will be resolved before `echo`.

Then function `echo` will be resolved and echo contain `to` as first and if you use `print()` inside echo, it will print the function parameter as first and then number `1`.

As **Andreas Scheibleger** mentioned in comment, the `1` comes from the return value of `print` which is always `1`, because it is not possible to echo a `print()` function.

For example:

```
echo print("");     // 1
echo print("test"); // test1
```

Comment: To add a note, The `1` comes from the return value of `print` which is always `1`

Comment: To add a note, you shouldn't `echo` a `print`.

Comment: But why `print('2')+2` outputs `4`? I'd expect this expression to evaluate to `3`, as `print()` always returns `1`, but apparently it's evaluated like `print('2' + 2)`?????

Comment: @MadDog `print()` is a language construct, which return the string, for example `print("test")` will return `test`. But if you use `print()` inside `echo`, it will print the string and then 1, but the 1 is output of the `print()` inside `echo`. `echo "2"+2;` will return `4` too. And because in this case is print inside echo, as first will be resolved `print('2')+2;` and this will print `4` to the start of the line and then will be resolved echo, which contain `'to'.print('2')+2;` and this will return `to1`